# Vuex: Add Dynamic Property to Object without triggering Watchers on existing Properties

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a Vuex store with an object:

```
 state: {
    contents: {},
 }
```

where I dynamically store contents by key:

```
mutations: {
   updateContent: (state, { id, a, b }) => {
       Vue.set(state.contents, id, { a, b });
   },
}
```

and get them using:

```
getters: {
    content: (state) => (id) => {
        if (id in state.contents) return state.contents[id];
        return [];
    }
},
```

Let's say I have a component like this:

```
export default {
    props: ["id"],
    computed: {
       myContent() {
          return this.$store.getters.content(this.id)
       }
    },
    // ...
}
```

How can I add dynamic properties using the mutation without triggering changes in components watching unchanged, already existant properties of `state.contents`?

Also see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ericskaliks/Ln0uws9m/15/).

Comment: In theory it is block the setters, but you can also just make a computed that watches only this property and adds this to a frozen objecct from outside of vue e.g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could use a global event bus instead of a vuex getter:

```
const eventBus = new Vue();
```

components can subscribe to the element they need:

```
 watch: {
    id: {
        handler(n, o) {
            if (o) eventBus.$off(o + "", this.onChange);
            eventBus.$on(n + "", this.onChange);
            this.$store.dispatch("request", { id: n });
        },
        immediate: true
    }
},
```

and changes of which the components have to be notified are dispatched using an action:

```
actions: {
    request(_, { id }) {
        eventBus.$emit(id + "", this.getters.content(id));
    },
    updateContent({ commit }, { id, a, b }) {
        commit("updateContent", { id, a, b });
        eventBus.$emit(id + "", { a, b });
    }
}
```

That way one can precisely control when which updates are fired.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ericskaliks/hmef4v9z/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch inner property of objects, you can use `deep watchers`.

In your situation, i am assuming you're setting properly yor getters, setter and update methods. You should add this to your watchers:

```
// ...
watch:{
  id: {
    deep: true,
    handler(newVal, oldVal){
      console.log("New value and old value: ", newVal, oldVal")
      // ... make your own logic here
    }
  }
}
```

Let me explain little bit more above code, when we want to watch inner property of any object in Vue, we should use `deep` and `handler` function to manipulate in every change. (remember that, handler is not a random name, it's reserved keyword)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I don't have a problem with the handler beeing not called - it is called *too often*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure it out by checking the fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/ericskaliks/Ln0uws9m/15/ , and I have a possible reason to this behavior.

Getters and Computed properties are updated or reached when the observed objects or properties inside them are changed. In this case the `content` getter is "watching" the `state.contents` store property, so each time `store.contents` is updated, the `content` getter is called, then the computed property `myContent()` updates its value and increase the `updated` data property with `this.update++`.

So the components will always be updated if the `state.contents` property is updated, i.e. adding a `new unrelated property`.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like Vue(x) can't do this out-of-the-box. But by adding an empty Observer (yes, this is a hack) you can make Vue-components temporarily nonreactive (based on this [blogpost](https://medium.com/@deadbeef404/tell-vue-js-to-stop-wasting-time-and-render-faster-7c3f7d2acaab)).

Basically - we have an Observer on the object itself and an Observer on each of the properties. We will destroy the Observer on the object. When doing so, we have to make sure, that when the getter is first called by a component it returns a reactive value rather then `{}`, because the getter can't observe adding a new property to the object anymore. Therefore, we add a `touch`-mutation initializing the object. This function needs the original Observer of the object to create Observers on its properties, causing one, but only one, unnecessary update of the component:

```
mutations: {
    updateContent: (state, { id, a, b }) => {
        Vue.set(state.contents, id, { a, b });
    },
    touch: (state, { id }) => {
            if(id in state.contents) return
        if (myObserver === null)
            myObserver = state.contents.__ob__
        state.contents.__ob__ = myObserver
        Vue.set(state.contents, id, {});
        state.contents.__ob__ = new Observer({});
    }
},
```

The constructor can be obtained using:

```
 const Observer = (new Vue()).$data.__ob__.constructor;
```

Our component has to call `touch` whenever the `id` changes:

```
props: ["id"],
watch: {
    i: {
        immediate: true,
        handler() {
            this.$store.commit("touch", { id: this.id })
        }
    }
},
computed: {
    myContent() {
        return this.$store.getters.content(this.id)
    }
},
```

As you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ericskaliks/5a2ms48k/), adding new properties to the object doesn't trigger unnecessary updates anymore.